# Update table row failed. The row contains a bad value

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, editing, hosted-feature-layer

I'm currently editing a table of a hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Pro. I cannot edit the table without receiving this error, which blocks my edits. There are no joins to it.

What I can remember doing leading up to this error is deleting a column with no values and cutting and pasting the text in random fields here and there. I can't say exactly what caused it.

I noticed that I can still edit the attributes in AGOL, however, and the edits are saved when I refresh the table in Pro.

```
Update table row.
Update table row failed.
The row contains a bad value.
[LORecyclingLocations_full]The row contains a bad
value. [Notes]An expected Field was not found or
could not be retrieved properly. [(class name:
LORecyclingLocations_full, oid: 6)]An expected Field
was not found or could not be retrieved preoperly.
[(class name: LORecyclingLocations_full, oid: 6)]
```

**EDIT:** It apparently had something to do with the field I was working on at the time. Because I moved on to another field making edits and I'm not receiving the error??

Comment: deleting the field caused data corruption, please use your backup to roll back.

Comment: OK, thanks. Mental note. If you're willing to put that, and maybe a reference, in an answer I'll except it.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Good to know. I changed the picture to text.